# LocalStorage works in localhost but not in production

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, local-storage

I am implementing a dark theme using React, Material-Ui and localStorage.

I have **setitem()** in my **handleThemeChange** function. Which works fine both on localhost and in production.

```
export const handleThemeChange = (State: stateProps, Dispatch: React.Dispatch<themeActionProps>) => {
  Dispatch(
    {
      type: themeActionTypes.CHANGE_THEME,
      payload: State.theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
    }
  )
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem('preferred-theme', State.theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
  }
}
```

But there is a problem in **getitem()**. When I reload the page it fetches and sets the theme according to the fetched result from local storage in localhost. However, When I refresh the page in production it doesn't set the theme according to localStorage but on initialValue.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import { darkTheme, lightTheme } from "../theme/theme";
import { stateProps, themeActionProps, themeActionTypes } from "../types/reducerTypes";

const initialState = {
    // theme: 'light'
    theme: typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('preferred-theme') ? localStorage.getItem('preferred-theme') : 'light' : 'light'
};

const themeReducer = (state: stateProps, action: themeActionProps) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case themeActionTypes.CHANGE_THEME:
            return {
                ...state,
                theme: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const GlobalStateContext = createContext(initialState);
export const GlobalDispatchContext = createContext<React.Dispatch<themeActionProps>>(() => { });

const ThemesProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(themeReducer, initialState);
    const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem('preferred-theme') ? localStorage.getItem('preferred-theme') : 'light' : 'light');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setTheme(state.theme);
    },[state.theme]);

    // To change the preferred theme
    // let theme = 'light';

    // if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    //     theme = localStorage.getItem('preferred-theme');        
    //     theme = theme ? theme : 'light';
    //     state.theme = theme        
    // }

    return (
        <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
                    {children}
                </ThemeProvider>
            </GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
        </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default ThemesProvider;
```

My [Github Repo](https://github.com/Mahmadabid/gatsby-dark-mode-mui) and [Demo](https://gatsby-dark-mode-mui.netlify.app/)

Comment: Since it seems you have already solved your issue, you maybe can post your solution for others and close the question?

Comment: Can you explain how you solve the issue ?